# Symfony newbie: can't get right VirtualHosts in Apache

Tags: apache, symfony1, symfony-1.4

starting developing with symfony and the only issue I face so far is the right web server set up. I'm not very familiar with Apache configs. I'm using a Plesk VPS with:

- CentOS 5.5
- Apache/2.2.3
- Symfony 1.4.17 (non-sanbox)

I have set up a subdomain sf.mydomain.com, where web-accessable path on the server is:

```
/var/www/vhosts/mydomain.com/subdomains/sf/httpdocs/
```

The symfony project is here:

```
/var/www/vhosts/mydomain.com/subdomains/sf/httpdocs/jobeet/
```

Symfony installation files are here:

```
/var/www/vhosts/mydomain.com/subdomains/sf/httpdocs/jobeet/lib/vendor/symfony/data/web/sf/
```

I know it's not recommended to have your installation under httpdocs, but I'm just testing it. In my httpd.conf I've added these entries:

```
NameVirtualHost *:80
    <VirtualHost *:80>
      ServerName sf.mydomain.com
      DocumentRoot "/var/www/vhosts/mydomain.com/subdomains/sf/httpdocs/jobeet/web"
      DirectoryIndex index.php
      <Directory "/var/www/vhosts/mydomain.com/subdomains/sf/httpdocs/jobeet/web">
        AllowOverride All
        Allow from All
      </Directory>

      Alias /sf /var/www/vhosts/mydomain.com/subdomains/sf/httpdocs/jobeet/lib/vendor/symfony/data/web/sf
      <Directory "/var/www/vhosts/mydomain.com/subdomains/sf/httpdocs/jobeet/lib/vendor/symfony/data/web/sf">
        AllowOverride All
        Allow from All
      </Directory>
    </VirtualHost>
```

My intention is to have a pretty welcoming screen at mydomain.com/jobeet/web, however now it doesn't display images and if also fails to route through /jobeet/web/sf/sf_default/css/screen.css. I know I can copy the "lib/vendor/symfony/data/web/sf/" over to "/web", but I want to know what am I doing wrong in here? Any tips would be highly appreciated.

Comment: With this config you should enter `http://sf.mydomain.com` (or `http://sf.mydomain.com/frontend_dev.php` for dev mode) in the browser. I think you must have a properly configured dns to use named virtual hosts (or if it's a local server add your host name and ip to /etc/hosts).

Comment: sf.mydomain.com leads to non-existing page :/ I've tried a number of variations with no luck. What should I look for in DNS? Thanks!

Comment: Try `nslookup sf.mydomain.com` on the same machine where you want to see the page. This command should return the IP address of your VPS machine. If not try to add it to the host file of that machine (where you used nslookup).

Comment: @Aidas did you resolve this problem?

Answer (score 0):

Have you tried to publish the assets using CLI, just try running the bellow task and this will publish symfony's default assets (the assets for doctrine plugin and so).

```
symfony plugin:publish-assets
```